# Removing articles from ResearchGate

Tags: publications, disreputable-publishers

Over a decade ago, when I was about 11, I fancied myself as budding social scientist and wrote a few "papers" of *extremely dubious quality*  which I uploaded to SSRN. I kept up the interest in academics, in physics, and recently became aware of their continued existence. I deleted them from SSRN, but it seems ResearchGate had already created pages automatically for them. I can remove the papers from my newly created profile but I can't find a way to delete the pages from accessibility via Google. I have quite a distinctive name, so there's no deniability there. What should I do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am not familiar with SSRN, but it seems that when you publish content there [you give SSRN a license to display the paper](https://www.ssrn.com/index.cfm/en/ssrn-faq/#ssrn_copyright), but this is not a transferable license like a Creative Commons one. If that's the case, and if you did not publish the paper on a journal or elsewhere, then you are the copyright holder and Researchgate does not have a license that allows them to publish it. Then they are infringing your copyright, and the correct legal step to take is filing a DMCA takedown request using [this PDF form](https://www.researchgate.net/images/RG_NOCI_v3.pdf).

IANAL.

Comment: Thank you! It worked!